Handling property value types in wrapper method for PATCH operations in Cosmos DB
I'm trying to create a generic wrapper method to perform PATCH operations in Cosmos DB.
Properties of documents will be of different types e.g. int, string, etc. I can pass a list of properties to update in a Dictionary<string, object> but how would I handle casting them to their proper type in the PatchOperation? More specifically, how can I get the data type of the property that I need to cast the value to?
public async Task UpdateProperties(string collectionId, string partitionKey, string id, Dictionary<string, object> updateParameters)
{
   List<PatchOperation> patchOperations = new();
   
   foreach(var item in updateParameters)
      patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Replace("/" + item.Key, item.Value)); // Here the value needs to be of type that corresponds to the property
}


If you trust the values in your updateParameters, Cosmos DB can handle them dynamically without requiring type casting. The PatchOperation.Replace method accepts
